# Why did King David think his census was sinful?

Tags: historical-interpretation, david, 2-samuel

King David entrusted Joab to "number Israel and Juda" ([2 Sam. 24:1](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=10&ch=24&l=1-#x)), then ([v. 10](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=10&ch=24&l=10#x)):

> David's heart struck him, after the people were numbered: and David said to the Lord: I have sinned very much in what I have done: but I pray thee, O Lord, to take away the iniquity of thy servant, because I have done exceeding foolishly.

H. McKay, O.F.M., *1 and 2 Kings (1 and 2 Samuel)*, in [*A Catholic Commentary on Holy Scripture*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7785) (Orchard et al. eds.), says (§ c 24:1–25):

> we are not told why this normal act of administration was sinful. David may have intended merely compiling a register for the organization of military service, fresh taxation, and forced labour for his building schemes. However it was a common belief amongst ancient Semitic peoples that whoever knew the name of a person, the number of his possessions, herds, and household acquired a mysterious power over them; *cf.* [RB [*Revue Biblique*] 53 (1946)](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/Q9L8QTZI/George%20-%201946%20-%20Fautes%20contre%20Yahweh%20dans%20les%20livres%20de%20Samuel.pdf) 178. Hence David’s action implied that he had absolute rights over his people, whereas he was merely Yahweh’s representative in a strictly theocratic state.

Is this the only explanation as to why King David thought he sinned by doing a census? Do the Fathers or Doctors of the Church give other explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is suggested by Exodus 30:12: "When you take the census of the people of Israel, then each shall give a ransom of himself to the Lord when you number them, that there be no plague among them when you number them" (RSV).

This offers a reason why the whole people would be at fault if a census was taken and no "ransom" was offered or demanded, and the penalty actually suffered by David's people is also set out in advance.

Comment: @ Stephen Disraeli Best answer! Biblically stated reason. Ex. 30:12.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Pride**

Some point to the prideful motive behind the census, suggesting that David's desire to know the full extent of his military strength and subjects reflected a lack of trust in God's protection and providence. They argue that David's action stemmed from a sense of self-reliance and a failure to acknowledge God as the ultimate source of strength and security.

[TENTH](https://www.tenth.org/resource-library/articles/why-was-davids-census-a-great-sin/) says:

> The parallel account in 1 Chronicles 21 says, “Satan rose up against
> Israel and incited David to take a census of Israel.” The record in
> Chronicles places this right after a great victory over the
> Philistines, so **the sin was probably related to a problem with pride
> and self-reliance.** A census was preliminary to a draft of soldiers and
> a levying of taxes. It seems, therefore, that David’s intent was to
> increase the royal power in a way that contrasted with humble reliance
> on God. As Deuteronomy chapter 17 so strongly insists, the human
> kingship of Israel was to be noticeably dependent on God’s divine
> kingship. **For Israel’s king to build up the same kind of power common
> to pagan kings was tantamount to repudiating God’s over-kingship.** This
> seems to have been the nature of David’s sin so that God was angered
> and acted to nip it in the bud.

2. **Possibly includes Levites in the army**

[ligonier](https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/davids-census) says:

> It all started when David took a census. In the ancient world, rulers
> would take a census either to levy taxes or to draft an army, and the
> counting of men “who drew the sword” indicates that David had the
> latter purpose in mind. Joab warned David that such a census would be
> sinful, most likely because it reflected a reliance on human strength
> in the form of a large standing army. The text also tells us that Joab
> did not include Levi in the census, “for the king’s command was
> abhorrent to Joab” (21:6). **The best explanation for this is that David
> asked Joab to include Levites in the army even though the law of God
> expressly ordered Israel to exclude Levites from a military census**
> (Num. 1). So, it seems that **David sinned because he was relying on
> military strength, not on the Lord, and was breaking God’s regulations
> for military eligibility.**